# AccessibilityService OnKeyEvent with screen off

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm using AccessibilityService OnKeyEvent to capture the Headsethook.  This is so I can trigger an event on key up, and key down, even if my app it not in focus.

However, it does not work once the screen goes off.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

`AccessibilityService` will not work when the screen is off. so to achieve the effort that catch `KeyEvent` when power down, You should use other alternatives.

if you only want to catch `HEADSETHOOK`, you can use `MediaButtonIntentReceiver` instead of `AccessibilityService`: register a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` intent, so can catch `KEYCODE_MEDIA_*` and `KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK` in background, also as the screen is off.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name="com.exmaple.MediaButtonReceiver"><intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"></action>  
</intent-filter></receiver>
```

`MediaButtonReceiver.java`

```
...
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
        int keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

if you do not want the other app to catch `HEADSETHOOK`, you should use `AudioManager` to register it:

```
...
AudioManager mAudioManager =(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
ComponentName  mbCN = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class.getName());  
mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mbCN);
... 
//mAudioManager.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(mbCN);
...
```

note: most music player apps also use `MediaButton`, when they register `MediaButton` receiver, your app will lose the focus of `AudioManager`, so you maybe should use `AudioFocusChangeListener` to listen the focus change and re-register.

if you also want to capture other keys in background. as far as i know, root is an all-right solution. you can use `getevent` command to catch all the log stream of input devices. then trigger the log of wanted keys.